# Не работает Wi-Fi на ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

При запуске ноутбука Honor Magicbook 15 AMD на ОС Ubuntu 22.04 LTC не работает Wi-Fi, а точнее он подключается к нему, но интернет соединения нет. Браузер Google Chrome выдает это:[image: Google Chrome]

Однако, если в терминале написать команду: **sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved** - то все начинает исправно работать. Пытался менять DNS, не помогает, прокси-серверов и брандмауэров нет. Предположительно ошибка появилась после попытки изменения DNS через файл **/etc/systemd/resolved.conf**. Там тоже пытался ставить другие DNS, но безуспешно, на данные момент файл в исходном состоянии.

Comment: а в чём ваш вопрос заключается? «как починить»? для этого вы привели катастрофически мало информации.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, вы правы, я действительно забыл сказать, что необходимо решить проблему, вопрос именно такой. Однако, решение в данном случае может быть не только "починка", ведь чинят сломанное, а в данной проблеме явных поломок нет. Вариант с авто-запуском команды  **sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved** не самый лучший, однако тоже является решение проблемы. Если вам кажется, что информации "катастрофически мало", это не значит, что ее недостаточно для решения другим пользователям сайта. Если у вас остались ещё какие-то вопросы, необходимые для решения проблемы, я на них отвечу.

Comment: `Вариант с авто-запуском команды sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved не самый лучший`, возможно вы случайно удалили сервис systemd-resolved из автозагрузки ? выполните команду `sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved` и перезагрузитесь.